# Did anyone make a count of the number of times Egwene/Nynaeve/Elayne got caught?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, statistics

They got caught so easily and I just wonder if they got caught more in the future.

From what I can remember (up to *The Shadow Rising*),

- Egwene and Perrin got caught by the Children of the Light. Moiraine/Lan/Nynaeve saved them. (*The Eye of the World*)
- Egwene got caught in Toman Head by the Seanchan. Nynaeve and Elayne saved her. (*The Great Hunt*)
- Egwene/Nynaeve/Elayne got caught by Darkfriends in a wilderness, and were rescued by Aiels (*The Dragon Reborn*)
- Egwene/Nynaeve/Elayne got caught by the Black Ajah in Tear, and were rescued by Mat and Juilin Sandar (*The Shadow Rising*).

Comment: Given that Elayne's safety plan seems to be "throw myself headlong at whatever dangerous people I can possibly find and hope they aren't expecting it", this is gonna be a really high number.

Comment: On the same note, do we have statistics on how many times Nynaeve pulled her braid, or *any* female character sniffed? :D

Comment: @SystemDown Count the total number of pages Jordan wrote, and divide by 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oddly enough, once they split up after *The Shadow Rising*, their track record improves significantly. Since they are frequently apart for the rest of the series, we have to follow each separately:

- Nynaeve does the best of them. She is never taken hostage again after being rescued from Tear.
- Egwene is captured once more, by Elaida, while Egwene is acting as Amyrlin for the rebel half of the White Tower. She does redeem herself a bit by effectively rescuing herself (and becoming Amyrlin Seat in the process.)
- Elayne is also captured one more time, by the Black Ajah, while being incredibly stupid. She's rescued by Birgitte and a rescue party.

Also, while I wouldn't count it as being "caught" in the sense of held hostage, there's a further incident

> during the Last Battle, where Elayne is captured one more time by Darkfriends and a false "dead Queen" shown to the armies to break their spirit. A resurrected Birgitte rescues her some indeterminate amount of time later (presumably not very long.)

Comment: Nynaeve does get ambushed in Ebou Dar (IIRC), trapped underwater and almost drowned. I think she rescues herself and then someone else pulls her from the drink. But it's probably best to leave excluded, as that even came more from the agency of the Dark than the spirit of what the questioner was asking.